# Symfony fresh installation is not working on my localhost

Tags: php, symfony, terminal, xampp, symfony-console

I installed a fresh copy of Symfony on my localhost at htdocs\symfony-fresh and the file structure is: 
[image]

Now I run the following in git bash:

```
$ php bin/console server:run
```

then I was suggested to browse at `127.0.0.1:8000` to see the fresh installation of symfony. It works like a charm. But one day later I browse at `127.0.0.1:8000` and I can see the following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

It seems server is offline. I checked my apache & Mysql is running. 
[image]

Then I tried to run the command again:

```
$ php bin/console server:run
```

But same problem is going on. I am new in Symfony and enjoying to learn, but this problem stuck me. What should I do to run this app browsing at 127.0.0.1/symfony-fresh or localhost/symfony-fresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check status follow:

```
php bin/console server:status
```

By default, the web server listens on port 8000 on the loopback device. You can change the socket passing an IP address and a port as a command-line argument:

```
# passing a specific IP and port
php bin/console server:start 192.168.0.1:8080

# or like this
php bin/console server:start *:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache has nothing to do with this, the built in Symfony server is based  on php built in server (`php -S ...`)

The built in server is intended for development use only, you must run the command every time the server has stopped or the machine has rebooted.

If you want to use Symfony with apache you can setup a virtualhost: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html